# MVC3 redirect on first login

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, redirect

Using MVC3 razor, I want to redirect a user on firstlogin to ClubController. I am using the default Membership provider and Profile provider I have set a boolean isNewUser to true during registration. The code is below but it  seems the logic is not in order. I am a novice and need help.

```
    [HttpPost] 
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                var userProfile = ProfileBase.Create(model.UserName);
                var FirstTime = userProfile.GetPropertyValue("isNewUser");
               if (FirstTime == true)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Create", "Club");
                }
                else
                {

                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                        && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                    {
                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }

                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
                    }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

I have  followed steps at [How to track first login of user in MVC3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354963/how-to-track-first-login-of-user-in-mvc3).  Any help will be very much appreciated

Comment: Did you set the default value for the custom property in the configuration to 'true' `<add name="isNewUser" defaultValue="True" type="System.Boolean" />`  and you should also set the value to false before redirecting to the ClubController

Comment: what's in your `ProfileBase.Create` method?

Comment: yes I have done the configuration  bit as follows `<profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
      <properties>
        <add name="isNewUser" defaultValue="False" type="System.Boolean"/>
      </properties>
    </profile>`  I think the problem is the arrangement of the if and else as above if somebody could check that for me

Comment: I get ModelState underlined in green  and a warning states unreacheable code detected

Comment: @Diin the default value should be `true`, so that when you create the user profile when he logs in for the first time the property "isNewUser" is set correctly, and as mentioned in the previous comment of mine you need to set the value to `false` before redirecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this is how I managed to get it work out. I made the logon model as below

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
    {
      FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
      var profile = ProfileBase.Create(model.UserName);
      var FirstTime = profile.GetPropertyValue("isNewUser");
      var chk=FirstTime; 
      if (chk.Equals(true))
        return RedirectToAction("Create","Club");
      else
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
            && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
          return Redirect(returnUrl);
        else
          return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else
      ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
  }
```

And set the config file as follows

```
<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
  <properties>
    <add name="isNewUser" type="System.Boolean"/>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tak out the { and } before and after the model state line

Comment: thanks @Ryand.Johnson I managed to fix that one but no matter the value of FirstTime this line
` return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");` before the model state line executes

Comment: @Krishna Chytanya I had wanted to set it to false after the the club has been filled completely. But now even when I create a new user I was expecting the isNewUser to register as true in the default profile provider but that does not even work

Comment: Do I have to add a setting at the register part of account controller?

Comment: @torm torm can you help out here

Comment: i have added code to set isNewUser to default value on registration in AccountController so that bit is sorted. My problem is no matter the differences in the values of isNewUser in the profile properties they all act the same either they redirect or not

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure FirstTime is a boolean and not a string?  You could change your if statement to make sure

```
if(Convert.ToBoolean(FirstTime))....
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I have done as you suggested but When I track by setting breakpoints FirstTime is always True for any user but even that it does not redirect